# Spring Boot Gradle quickbuild that skips the non-essentials

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Java 8 and Gradle 4.6 here. I have a Spring Boot app with the following `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'jacoco'
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    dev
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        ,'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
        ,'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25'
        ,'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.9.1'
        ,'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
        ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
        ,'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.2'
        ,'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:1.8.3'
    )

    testCompile(
        'junit:junit:4.12'
        ,'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'
    )

    dev('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
String buildName = 'myapp'

jar {
    baseName = buildName
}

bootRun {
    if(project.hasProperty('debugMode')) {
        jvmArgs = [ "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" ]
    }

    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + configurations.dev
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '8.12'
    ignoreFailures = false
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        html.enabled true
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/")
    }
}

check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
jacocoTestCoverageVerification.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
```

So this is a Spring Boot Java app that also uses the [Checkstyle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html) and [Jacoco](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html)  Gradle plugins.

I consider a "*full build*" to be an invocation that:

- Compiles
- Runs Checkstyle
- Runs unit tests (JUnit)
- Runs Jacoco for code coverage analysis
- Uses Spring Boot's libraries to build a "fat" (self-contained) executable jar

Given my current Gradle build file, I run a full build like so:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

However this can take several minutes to run through all the unit tests and has become cumbersome. I would like to introduce a
"*quick build*" option that only compiles the code and creates the Spring Boot fat jar for me. This will help speed up development
time tremendously.

I'm hoping to invoke the quick build like so:

```
./gradlew clean quickbuild
```

So far I've got this:

```
tasks.register("quickbuild") { 
    doLast { 
        // ???
    }
}
```

But not sure how to link the compilation and fatjar tasks to it (and more importantly; skipping all the other stuff that I don't want!). **Any ideas as to what I'm missing?**

---

#### Update

The `bootJar` task doesn't seem to exist or be configured (please check my `build.gradle` file provided above!):

```
$ ./gradlew clean bootJar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'bootJar' not found in root project 'myapp'. Some candidates are: 'bootRun'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

When I try to run `bootRun`:

```
$ ./gradlew clean bootRun
```

It tries to actually *run* my app! That's not what I want! I just want to compile and build the fat jar!

Comment: (Gradle 5 here) I tried `gradle bootJar` in my environment and it does not run tests or related stuff.

Comment: Thanks @jingx (+1) please see my update above regarding `bootJar` but it doesn't appear to be applicable for my given Gradle configuration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation from the Java plugin here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#lifecycle_tasks

You could create a new task (`quickbuild`) and make it depend on the desired task (in your case it could be the `assemble` lifecycle task, I guess, or maybe `bootJar` task (for SpringBoot v2.x) or `bootRepackage` (for SpringBoot v1.5.x) )

```
tasks.register('quickbuild'){
    dependsOn assemble
}
```

But if the only purpose of `quickbuild` task is to trigger the creation of the Jar, the simpliest solution is to execute `assemble` directly

```
./gradlew clean assemble
```

Comment: Thanks @M.Ricciuti (+1) - does `assemble` call `bootJar` (or whatever Spring Boot is doing under the hood to create the fat jar)? Or does `assemble` invoke Gradle's own built-in fat jar mechanism? I ask because its very important to me that whatever Spring Boot fat-jar-building-related tasks are invoked by running `./gradlew clean build` are also invoked during this "quick build" as well! Thanks again!

Comment: yes, when SpringBoot plugin is applied , it creates the `bootJar` task, and automatically configures the `assemble` task to depend on it.`It also disable by default the `jar` task. You can find some details in Spring Boot plugin doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-jars

Comment: Thanks @M.Ricciuti (+1 again) please see my update above regarding `bootJar` but it doesn't appear to be applicable for my given Gradle configuration!

Comment: sorry I missed the fact you are using SpringBoot v1.5.8 (I'm using latest version 2.1.x) : in v1.5.x the SpringBoot plugin is a bit different, there is no `bootJar` task but a `bootRepackage` task: see documentation related to your version here :  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-understanding-the-gradle-plugin   . The idea is the same: the `assemble` task is configured to depend on `bootRepackage` => you can execute directly `./gradlew clean bootRepackage`